# Javascript - how to create an array of objects where the object's keys all have the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I created a descending array of integers from the current year to 1930 using `moment`:

```
options = Array(moment().year() - 1929).fill().map((_, index) => moment().year() - index)
```

I'm trying to convert `options` into an array of objects such that the resulting array is something like this:

```
[{value: '2018', label: '2018'}, {value: '2017', label: '2017'}, ..., {value: '2', label: '2'}, {value: '1', label: '1'}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `.map` each item to an object instead of to a single number:

```js
const options = Array(moment().year() - 1929)
  .fill()
  .map((_, index) => {
    const value = moment().year() - index;
    return { value, label: value };
  });
console.log(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What What you want is another `map`. `map` will always take an array of a given length in an order and produce another array of the same length in the same order (in JS). So if we take your code and then add on:

`options.map(o => o.toString).map(o => ({ value: o, label: o }))`

you'd get get your objects.